# Identify users that are enabled and disabled in a CSV file from Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I can get the list of users from Active Directory using the "Get-ADUser" PowerShell cmdlet. And I can export it to a CSV file.

But is there a way I can have a column on the CSV file that says whether the accounts are enabled or disabled (or something like true or false for enabled or disabled).

Thanks

Comment: Yes, `Get-ADUser` returns the `Enabled` Property by default. if it's `True`, the User is enabled, if it's `False`, the User is disabled

Comment: Dude,can you shared the command please.

Comment: Dude, if you do what you say you already do, then you have an enabled property in your csv by default. just `Get-ADUser` and then pipe to `Export-CSV` and that's it.

Comment: Dudes.... [Dude, dude, dude, dude, du, dude, dude, dude.... dude-elodeon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsLa_HuoWGs) ... Just replace Nick with Dude.

Comment: There are tons of examples all over the web for this. Use tools that will write this for you. [Windows Server provides such a tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/active-directory-administrative-center). Use the GUI to click-thru what you want, save the PowerShell code create to use as is, or tweak as needed. [Use AD Administrative Center to Create PowerShell Commands](https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands). You can also just use `Search-ADAccount`. See the examples in the help files.

Comment: [A direct web search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20get%20active%20directory%20user%20status%20enable%20disabled%20to%20csv%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=poget%20active%20directory%20user%20status%20enable%20disabled%20to%20csv&sc=0-57&sk=&cvid=D4C67492A61F42B9848B49A7420A2689) would give you such info. [For Example](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/active_directory__powershell_remoting-9/20099/ad-accounts-disabled-enabled-query).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the specific properties you want, separated by commas.

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Enabled | Export-Csv -Path C:\AD_users.csv`